# Wavelet Transfrom + Power Spectral Density (using Matlab)

Tags: matlab, fft, power-spectral-density, eeg

I don't have background knowledge about signal processing before and new at Matlab too.

I have EEG data (with noise removed) 1x128; sampling rate = 128 Hz, It's means that I have 1 sec. data right?

OK, I need to extracted to 5 frequency bands that are Delta (0-4 Hz), Theta (4-8 Hz), Alpha (8-16 Hz), Beta (16- 32 Hz) and Gamma (32-64 Hz) by Wavelet Transform (using Matlab), What is/are function--commands should I use?

And then, I need to compute the power spectrum (PSD) for each band, What is/are function--commands should I use?

Example:

```
Input: X = [1:128] and I need
Output: Y = [psdOfDelta, psdOfTheta, psdOfAlpha, psdOfBeta, psdOfGamma]
```

Thanks.

Comment: i have the same problem and i do not know how to use wavelet or FFT to get power spectrum density, so please i need help.

Comment: @shereen I used this method http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/31413-computing-delta-power-of-eeg-signal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do 1-Dimensional wavelet package decomposition. [Here](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/wavelet/ref/wpdec.html) is the matlab documentation for the command to do this.

Here is some example code based on what you've described above:

```
wpt = wpdec(X, 2, 'db1', 'shannon')
plot(wpt)
```

This will provide a nice clickable graph. As you'll see in the documentation, you can provide a lot of different parameters for the decomposition.